# Imageio python Heroku read only access error

Tags: python, heroku, tesseract

Hi i am deplying a scanner using pytesseract. While scanning the file imageio is creating a temp BMP file in the system but due to Heroku's policy of only allowing read only access to the libraries ,I am not able to run my code. I am getting following error.

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/core/request.py", line 328, in get_file

2020-06-29T05:08:44.787037+00:00 app[web.1]: self._file = open(self.filename, "wb")
2020-06-29T05:08:44.787037+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/tmptess_105rvap2.bmp'
```

Can anyone please help me out how can I resolve it or how can I save the image in my personal Temp folder in heroku. uploading screenshot as well.
[image]

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem it is possible to write on a Heroku filesystem but the information will be lost. You cannot however write anywhere. Writing directly under `/` is not allowed. Try writing into `/app/yourfilename.bmp`.

Comment: i am trying to save it in my own tmp folder but problem is im using multiple libraries and all of them are writing temp file which is part of the library. now i dont know how to tackle or change mutiple packages as heroku installs new package in every deployment